# Jasmine mock call to service not mocking values

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this method, that calls a service inside.

```
searchUser() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.usersService.searchEmailandName(this.corporateId.value).subscribe(
        (data: UserSearch) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.email.patchValue(data.email);
            this.name.patchValue(data.name);
            this.checkInputs();
        }, error => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.errorGeneric.errorGeneric(error, 'search_user');
            this.email.patchValue('');
            this.name.patchValue('');
        }
    );
}
```

I'm trying to properly test it:

```
it('should test searchUser ', (done) => {
    usersService = TestBed.get(UsersService);

    component.corporateId.patchValue(userProfile.user.corporateId);
    component.searchUser();
    spyOn(usersService, 'searchEmailandName').and.returnValue(of(userProfile.user));

    expect(component.email.value).toBe('mock name');
    expect(component.name.value).toBe('mock@email.com');
    done();
});
```

user profile has all the info I need mocked.
I receive this error

```
Error: Expected undefined to be 'mock name'.
```

So I'm probably not doing the spy correctly or just missundertand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the `spyOn` before calling the method.

```
it('should test searchUser ', (done) => {
    usersService = TestBed.get(UsersService);

    component.corporateId.patchValue(userProfile.user.corporateId);
    // spy first before calling the method
    spyOn(usersService, 'searchEmailandName').and.returnValue(of(userProfile.user));
    component.searchUser();

    expect(component.email.value).toBe('mock name');
    expect(component.name.value).toBe('mock@email.com');
    done();
});
```

Comment: That worked! I knew it was a silly mistake. Thanks!